# React Native: Detect change in location setting

Tags: android, react-native, geolocation

I have a hard time detecting when the user enables location from the status bar so coordinates could be retrieved immediately. Any ideas on this? Is it supported at all? I wasn't able to find something helpful about this...

Comment: Just because they enable location doesn't mean one is available.  GPS (and even network) lookup takes time.  And Android doesn't waste the processing/battery power of calculating it if nobody is using it.

Comment: @GabeSechan thanks for the comment. My question was how the application can be aware of when location (and even wi-fi) services are enabled from the status bar so it can re-render?

Comment: You can detect when the user allows location access in the `successCallback` function of the `Geolocation.watchPosition(successCallback, [errorCallback], [options])` method.